# Android layout views with matching widths and heights

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new to android and trying to create a layout like so:

```
----------
|  y  | x|
----------
|  |  |  |
----------
|     |  |
----------
```

Box marked x has equal width and height, box y has 2 * x width. width x + y is full width of screen. all 3 rows are equal height, where row height matches the width and height of x. Is there a way to accomplish this in xml? The closest I've gotten is the following xml, but the row heights don't match the width of box x. Any ideas?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:text="text is here"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:text="and text is here"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#ffffffff"
            android:text="text is here"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#ffffffff"
            android:text="and text is here"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#ffffffff"
            android:text="and text is here"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use GridLayou:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:columnCount="4"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_columnSpan="3"
            android:text="1"/>

    <Button android:text="2"/>

    <Button android:text="3"/>

    <Button android:text="4"/>

    <Button android:text="5"/>

    <Button android:text="6"/>

    <Button
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_columnSpan="3"
            android:text="7"/>

    <Button android:text="8"/>    

</GridLayout>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: GridLayout looks like a good approach. How to make it fit screen width and adjust the boxes so they are squares? I'm trying with weight and 0dp width/height but it doesn't work.

Comment: You can do it from code or using custom square views.